No host described in new configuration with {version: 1, term: 0} for replica set rs0 maps to this node
Problem:- The pod was not Ready (0/1), and the pod status was Running. Error is pod was not rs.initiate()
I saw the pod logs and got the below error message.

{“t”:{“$date”:“2024-07-19T05:44:52.000+00:00”},“s”:“W”, “c”:“QUERY”, “id”:23799, “ctx”:“ftdc”,“msg”:“Aggregate command executor error”,“attr”:{“error”:{“code”:26,“codeName”:“NamespaceNotFound”,“errmsg”:“Unable to retrieve storageStats in $collStats stage :: caused by :: Collection [local.oplog.rs] not found.”},“stats”:{},“cmd”:{“aggregate”:“oplog.rs”,“cursor”:{},“pipeline”:[{“$collStats”:{“storageStats”:{“waitForLock”:false,“numericOnly”:true}}}],“$db”:“local”}}}


Also I describe the pod then I founded the Warring message from pod.


Warning Unhealthy 51s (x505 over 75m) kubelet Readiness probe failed: Error: Not ready

I installed bitnami/mongodb helm chart version 15.6.12 in the EKS cluster using this below command with replicaset configuration
helm install mongodb bitnami/mongodb --version 15.6.12
--set auth.rootPassword=<root_password> \
--set architecture=replicaset \
--set replicaCount=1 \
--set externalAccess.enabled=true \
--set externalAccess.autoDiscovery.enabled=true \
--set serviceAccount.create=true \
--set automountServiceAccountToken=true \
--set rbac.create=true \
--set externalAccess.service.type=LoadBalancer \
--set persistence.storageClass=gp2 

After this error I found some blogs I saw that, MongoDB replication was not initiate
Screenshot of pod logs
I want to deploy mongodb with replicase.

I have recently encountered similar problem. My values:
architecture: replicaset
auth:
    enabled: true
    rootUser: root
    rootPassword: XXXXX
    replicaSetKey: ""
    existingSecret: ""
replicaCount: 3

There was a problem in pod logs:
mongodb 08:41:58.45 WARN  ==> Problem initiating replica set request: 
rs.initiate({"_id":"rs0", "members":[{"_id":0,"host":"mongodb-0.mongodb-headless.databases.svc.cluster.local:27017","priority":5}]})

and
MongoServerError[InvalidReplicaSetConfig]: No host described in new configuration with {version: 1, term: 0} for replica set rs0 maps to this node

The reason was that the cluster dns can't resolve:
mongodb-0.mongodb-headless.databases.svc.cluster.local

because cluster domain was not "cluster.local".
Use kubectl get cm coredns -n kube-system -o jsonpath="{.data.Corefile}"  to figure out cluster domain.
And add value clusterDomain to values for example:
clusterDomain: somecluster.dev
or
--set clusterDomain = somecluster.dev
Maybe this will have some one who forget to set it up.
In your case with

--set externalAccess.enabled=true

Try to nslookpup your hosts: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/
